# Use VBA on new rows and not on existing rows

Tags: vba, excel

Good Morning!

I am currently writing an Excel form with VBA backed functions. These functions will allow the user to 1. add a new input line to the spreadsheet, 2. wipe the sheet of data and return it to its original configuration and 3. Copy the data in the sheet to a data accumulation sheet.

So far, I have point 2. completed and am working on 1., I have encountered a problem inside a loop. The problem being that this loop keeps repeating itself (that's the point of loops...) over and again on cells which it doesn't have to. I have a sneaking suspicion that it is in the loop's iteration counter that I should make a change so that it doesn't always start up at the beginning again, but I am lost as to how to do it. The loop's function is to give the value 1 to appropriate cells depending on which option box has been selected by the user. As it is, the code rewrites the whole column instead of just the row it should be at. Thus, data is lost in cells which had been filled in before.

The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub NextLineRed()

Dim i As Long
Dim End Row As Long

EndRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(Rows.Count.1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 19 To EndRow + 1 Step 1
        If MétalButton.Value = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 7).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 8).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 9).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 10).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 11).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 12).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 13).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 7) = 1
        End If

        If TMétalButton.Value = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 7).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 8).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 9).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 10).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 11).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 12).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 13).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 8) = 1
        End If

        If ContaButton.Value = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 7).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 8).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 9).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 10).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 11).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 12).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 13).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 9) = 1
        End If

        If MottonButton.Value = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 7).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 8).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 9).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 10).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 11).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 12).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 13).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 10) = 1
        End If

        If TrouButton.Value = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 7).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 8).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 9).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 10).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 11).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 12).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 13).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 11) = 1
        End If

        If TombéButton.Value = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 7).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 8).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 9).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 10).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 11).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 12).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 13).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 12) = 1
        End If

        If AutreButton.Value = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 7).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 8).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 9).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 10).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 11).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 12).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 13).ClearContents
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges").Cells(i, 13) = 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: [D.R.Y.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)  Learn it.  Embrace it.  Your code is very "WET".  Reduce repetition makes it easier to see bugs (among many, many other benefits).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you have made a function in wich you clear the cells from 7 to 13

Comment: @user3980820 -- *Exactly* my point.

Comment: No doubt my code is "WET", I am rather new to programming and quite ignorant. However, the reduction of repetitive code lines is not the question here (there's a loop joke in there). Clearing the cells is a formality really, as they should be blank to begin with. I suppose removing the associated lines would not change the output much. Now, the question is how to point the loop at the right spot on the worksheet for it not to redo rows which it doesn't have to.

Comment: can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's shorten this up a bit:  (This allows the user to select MULTIPLE Button conditions)

```
Private Sub NextLineRed()

Dim i As Long
Dim EndRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Drapeaux Rouges")
EndRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ws1.Range(Cells(EndRow, 7), Cells(EndRow, 13)).ClearContents
            If MétalButton.Value = True Then ws1.Cells(EndRow, 7) = 1
            If TMétalButton.Value = True Then ws1.Cells(EndRow, 8) = 1
            If ContaButton.Value = True Then ws1.Cells(EndRow, 9) = 1
            If MottonButton.Value = True Then ws1.Cells(EndRow, 10) = 1
            If TrouButton.Value = True Then ws1.Cells(EndRow, 11) = 1
            If TombéButton.Value = True Then ws1.Cells(EndRow, 12) = 1
            If AutreButton.Value = True Then ws1.Cells(EndRow, 13) = 1

End Sub
```

Comment: I still see `"Drapeaux Rouges"` repeated over and over.  Can't you just make a constant at the top?

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know how and couldn't find how to call a range in the Cells(#, #) notation and not in the ("A1:A1") notation.
@roryap Maybe a Drapeaux Rouges as a root and a With would reduce that repetition?

Comment: @Chrismas007 Only the last row. Thank you for the help. Testing it now and rewriting a lot of stuff so as to make it shorter with the means you showed me here.

Comment: you should propably remove the next from the last line

Comment: @Chrismas007 Marvelous! Just had to tweak by removing the +1 to the EndRow value as it was writing values in one row lower than I wanted.
Thank you all for the help and suggestions!